Getting PHP Warning: call_user_func_array()
i found in my error log which was more than 45Gb
[25-Dec-2024 15:23:02 UTC] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class '' not found in /home/site/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
no function or class name
how can i solve it ?
i tried deactivating each plugin and did not stop making the error

It would be helpful to see exactly that part of the source code including a trace.
